# Is there a way to access an iframe scroll position in React?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I tried with useRef, but i'm not receiving anything. Is there something wrong with my code or is it simply not possible to access an iframe scroll?

```
const iframeRef = useRef(null);

const onScroll = (e) =\> {
if (e?.target) {
const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = e.target;
if ((scrollTop + clientHeight) / scrollHeight \> 1) {
// TO SOMETHING HERE
console.log('Reached bottom');

      }
    }

};
```

```
<iframe
        ref={iframeRef}
        src={document.path}        
        onScroll={onScroll}
      />
```